# Embed Excel Charts into Powerpoint Issue

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, microsoft-powerpoint-2010

I am currently experiencing an issue with powerpoint 2010. I have created a three part chart in Excel and am trying to export it to powerpoint. However whenever I try to paste special the excel as an embed I am given no option to pase as an embed. It use to work seamlessly for me but I have been having this issue every time I log into powerpoint. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried selecting all three parts of the chart while in excel and Ctrl-C and Ctrl-V into powerpoint?

I was not able to duplicate your problem with PowerPoint 2010 and Excel 2010

Answer (score 0):

PPT no longer gives you this exact option in the old PasteSpecial dialog box (the one that listed all of your paste options).  But when you click the arrowhead beneath Paste, you'll see four icons under Paste Options.

Hover the mouse cursor over each for a quickie description of what it does.  One will be to embed and preserve the formatting of the presentation you're embedding into; another will be to preserve the original formatting.  The other two, as I recall, are paste as picture options.